# Square Cash Label Animation

Tags: ios, animation, uilabel, core-animation, cabasicanimation

Does anyone know how Square Cash animates their label?

The label does two things, appears to resize to fit the numbers on screen like SizeToFit might, but I don't believe that you can animate based on SizeToFit.

Secondly, numbers that disappear seem to animate downwards and disappear. Numbers that are entered animate down from above. That doesn't seem too tricky, but the comma does it too when we go from 4 digits to 5 digits!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I coded something similar and yes, it is very tricky to make it perfect.

It may help you to know that I used collection views. Then you can customise cell/layout transitions.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

It would be helpful if you posted a short video so we could see the animation you are talking about.

Based on your description, I'm guessing that they build the full number themselves by putting a single digit/symbol on a layer (or view) and then animating each character separately.

If you have a separate tile for each symbol it is pretty easy to change the size of the previous tiles to make room for a new tile, and animate a new number tile down at the same time. You could do the animation with UIView animation or with a set of coordinated CABasicAnimations.

Answer (score 0):

I know the answer is late but may be help to some other,

I developed demo screen similar to square cash you can check [here](https://github.com/mitsBhadeshiya/Square_Cash_NumPad)